# Server-side processing Datatable sort is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I'm using datatables in my administration panel

[image: viz1]

but I realized that the sort functionality is not working properly. The specific table that we're talking about is with server-side rendering. The specific column "Status" that we're talking about has the following contents

```
if($record->claimed == 1) {
     $claimed = '<span class="badge badge-primary">CLAIMED</span>';
 } else {
     $claimed = '<span class="badge badge-secondary">NOT CLAIMED</span>';
 }
```

How can I make this sort work properly? I tried this

```
if($record->claimed == 1) {
     $claimed = '<span class="d-none">1</span><span class="badge badge-primary">CLAIMED</span>';
 } else {
     $claimed = '<span class="d-none">0</span><span class="badge badge-secondary">NOT CLAIMED</span>';
 }
```

but it doesn't work as expected. Maybe some kind of a data-sort attribute or....? Any ideas?

Comment: Share your database query, fixing the sort there would be easier. `data-sort` only works when you're going to sort with javascript

Comment: What makes you think your shown code dealing with one specific property of one single record, had anything to do with _sorting_ all of them? https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters - your server-side script gets the parameters `order[i][column]` and `order[i][dir]` passed, and now it is your script's responsibility to properly sort the data that you will be returning, according to those criteria.

Comment: Full Controller Code - https://pastebin.com/41mPm90w

Comment: You're sorting by `created_at` or a defined column, but you're not sorting by claimed. I'd suggest adding that to your query, but before `created_at` since that would take priority. By the way, it's recommended that you [edit] your code and paste it here instead of providing an off-site link that may disappear.

Comment: @aynber Thanks for you suggestions, but to be honest I have no idea how to do what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issue when you populate your table cell with HTML tags, it creates issues for searching / sorting. A very simple TRICK to define your dataType as "JSON" will fix this issue. Below is my sample code for Datatable (Server-Side-Processing with pipelined) in my production server and working perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

        $.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
            // Configuration options
            var conf = $.extend( {
                pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
                url: '',      // script url
                data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                              // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
                method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
            }, opts );

            // Private variables for storing the cache
            var cacheLower = -1;
            var cacheUpper = null;
            var cacheLastRequest = null;
            var cacheLastJson = null;

            return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
                var ajax          = false;
                var requestStart  = request.start;
                var drawStart     = request.start;
                var requestLength = request.length;
                var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

                if ( settings.clearCache ) {
                    // API requested that the cache be cleared
                    ajax = true;
                    settings.clearCache = false;
                }
                else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
                    // outside cached data - need to make a request
                    ajax = true;
                }
                else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                    JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                    JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
                ) {
                    // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
                    ajax = true;
                }

                // Store the request for checking next time around
                cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

                if ( ajax ) {
                    // Need data from the server
                    if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                        requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

                        if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                            requestStart = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    cacheLower = requestStart;
                    cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);

                    request.start = requestStart;
                    request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

                    // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
                    if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
                        // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                        // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                        // data object to submit
                        var d = conf.data( request );
                        if ( d ) {
                            $.extend( request, d );
                        }
                    }
                    else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                        // As an object, the data given extends the default
                        $.extend( request, conf.data );
                    }

                    settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                        "type":     conf.method,
                        "url":      conf.url,
                        "data":     request,
                        "dataType": "json", // **IMPORTANT POINT**
                        "cache":    false,
                        "success":  function ( json ) {
                            cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);

                            if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                                json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                            }
                            if ( requestLength >= -1 ) {
                                json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
                            }

                            drawCallback( json );
                        }
                    } );
                }
                else {
                    json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
                    json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
                    json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
                    json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

                    drawCallback(json);
                }
            }
        };

        // Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
        // fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
        $.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
            return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
                settings.clearCache = true;
            } );
        } );
</script>
```